# SQL get the latest record

Tags: sql, date, row, combinations

I am struggeling here to pull out two results from this table. I have a table with different types, items and values which is added on different dates.

```
Type Item Value Date
1    10   111   20160101
1    10   122   20170101
1    11   222   20170101
1    12   312   20170101
2    10   144   20160101
2    10   155   20170101
2    11   105   20160101
2    11   133   20170101
2    11   123   20180101
3    10   111   20170101
```

First I would like only the lastest date, show on combination of type, item. I have tried this query, but it will show me all the dates.

```
SELECT Type, Item, Value, MAX(Date) as Date from TABLENAME
WHERE Type='1' or Type='2'
GROUP BY Type, Item, Value
```

Below is what I would like it to look like.

```
Type Item Value Date
1    10   122   20170101
1    11   222   20170101
1    12   312   20170101
2    10   155   20170101
2    11   123   20180101
```

Then we have the more tricky question, here I am totally lost and not sure if it is possible, or maybe I should do this in some other way? I would like to see if an item with type 1 has a value, while type 2 has not. Or the other way around. Displayed in a new table.

```
Item Type1 Type2 Date
10   1     2     20170101 -> Item 10 has values with both type 1,2 on specific date
11   1           20170101 -> Item 11 has only a value when type 1 on specific date
11         2     20180101 -> Item 11 has only a value when type 2 on specific date
12   1           20170101 -> Item 12 has only a value when type 1 on specific date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question I think you can use:

```
SELECT A.TYPE, A.ITEM, A.VALUE, A.DATE 
FROM TABLENAME A
INNER JOIN ON (SELECT TYPE, ITEM, MAX(DATE) AS MAXDATE
                FROM TABLENAME
                GROUP BY TYPE, ITEM) B ON A.TYPE = B.TYPE AND A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND A.DATE=B.MAXDATE
WHERE A.TYPE='1' OR A.TYPE='2'
```

For second you could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ITEM, B.TYPE AS TYPE1, C.TYPE AS TYPE2, CASE WHEN B.TYPE IS NOT NULL THEN B.DAT ELSE C.DAT END AS DATE_X 
FROM 
    (SELECT ITEM, TYPE, MAX(DATE) AS DAT
     FROM ITEM
     GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) A
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEM, TYPE, MAX(DATE) AS DAT FROM ITEM WHERE TYPE='1' GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND A.DAT= B.DAT
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEM, TYPE, MAX(DATE) AS DAT FROM ITEM WHERE TYPE='2' GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) C ON A.ITEM = C.ITEM AND A.DAT= C.DAT
```

Output       :

```
    ITEM    TYPE1   TYPE2   DATE_X
1   10  1   2   20170101
2   11  NULL    2   20180101
3   11  1   NULL    20170101
4   12  1   NULL    20170101
```

Comment: First one worked well when, just deleted the ON after INNER JOIN. Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use MS SQL. It almost seem to work, but I get a different result than you. The same but I get a NULL value in row 1 in Type2. It will not show values in both Type1 and Type2 at the same time.

Comment: Have you checked your sample data? Are they the same as you posted in your question?

Comment: You are right. The date has the same structure, but I realized the date was different in my samples. If I would do the same control just between the types and ignore the dates. How could I remove the dates then?

Comment: If any one of the answers solved your question, you should mark that answer.  If you have other question, I think you should post another question (with sample data and desired output sample).

Comment: Thanks a lot etsa! I appriciate it!

Comment: You can try this (I simply remove every reference to dates) but if it doesn't meet your new request, it should be better open another question, to have more "space" to write.   `SELECT DISTINCT A.ITEM, B.TYPE AS TYPE1, C.TYPE AS TYPE2 
FROM 
 (SELECT ITEM, TYPE 
  FROM ITEM
     GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEM, TYPE  FROM ITEM WHERE TYPE='1' GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM  
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEM, TYPE  FROM ITEM WHERE TYPE='2' GROUP BY ITEM, TYPE) C ON A.ITEM = C.ITEM `

Answer (score 0):

For your first scenario you can use the below query

```
SELECT Type, Item, Value, Date from TABLENAME
WHERE (Type='1' or Type='2') and date = (SELECT MAX(Date) from TABLENAME)
```

Comment: This query does not solve the first scenario. For instance, if the max date is different between two types it would discard the results from one of the types.